# Is it good to have hadoop Namenode and datanode in two different networks?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We are installing HA enabled 10 node Hadoop cluster by using Cloudera distribution.

Is it good to have Namenode and datanode on two different subnet which is secured through the hardware firewall ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as network requests work in both directions from the active namenode (assuming you setup HA) and every datanode, then should work fine, although the extra network hop would add some latency

Comment: I don't think the environment changes my answer

Answer (score 0):

In case of big data networks, large number of node to node interactions shall get generated from a single client interaction for getting the expected operation done or result (like clients reading more than a single block of data). Such  big data networks shall face performance impact due to additional hop count that can increase latency between the client, name node & job tracker and data node & task tracker when the data traverses between through rack switches.

Hadoop basically provides distributed processing of large data sets across clusters of computers which directly implies that networking plays a key role in deployment architecture and also directly associated with its performance and scalability. HDFS and MapReduce have high east-west traffic pattern.

In HDFS, if rack awareness configuration is enabled for HA, the replication is a continuous activity which happens across network based on replication factor. The shuffle phase involving the transfer of data from mapper to reducer in Hadoop is one of the most network bandwidth consuming activity as all the involved servers shall transfer data to every other simultaneously and this directly underlines the network topology.

Also,  RPC mechanism are used by platform services like HDFS, HBase, Hive when a client requests for the remote service to execute a function. Every RPC would require the response sent back to client as soon as possible and if there is a delay for the response to reach the client, then the execution of the command can take longer time.

*For optimum performance of hadoop, the network must have high bandwidth, low latency and reliable node connectivity across different nodes which boils down to having reduced hops as far as possible as one of the criteria.*

*In a typical network deployment, firewalls can impact cluster performance if placed between cluster nodes as they have to inspect the packets in network. Hence, it is better to avoid firewall between nodes in cluster.*